# Parametrisation of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to parameterise $M=\bigl\{(x,y,z) \mid e^z=\frac{\cos x}{\cos y}\bigr\}\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ where $x,y \in \bigl(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)$ in $(u,v)$ i.e $2$ variables but without any luck. Can someone see how that is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z=\ln\frac{\cos x}{\cos y}$, we immediately get the parametrisation
$$\left(x,y,\ln\frac{\cos x}{\cos y}\right)\qquad x,y\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$$

Comment: You have a tip for a general rule when doing this? Some good way to think about the problem?

Comment: @user1 No, it's just solving for $z$.

Comment: K, I guess I have to develop a few methods then. This as a first one.